# Intepretation of a statement in Algebraic Graph Theory book

Tags: graph-theory, algebraic-graph-theory

Currently reading *Algebraic Graph Theory* by Godsil and Royle, and I came across the following statement:

> If $X$ has no *triangles* (cliques of size three), then any vertex of $L(X)$ with at least two neighbours in one of these cliques must be contained in that clique. Hence the cliques determined by the vertices of X are all maximal.

$L(X)$ in this case is the line graph of $X$.

I'm having trouble interpreting this statement. Say that $X$ indeed has no triangles. Then I'm thinking that if $L(X)$ has two vertices such that the edges that they represent are part of the same clique in $X$, then it must either be the same vertex or there is a triangle since the third edge is adjacent to both of them. But we assumed that $X$ has no triangles. What am I missing here?

Comment: ...hence the cliques in $L(X)$....

Comment: @ChrisGodsil That makes sense now. I also reread the previous paragraph, and together with your clarification it makes sense. If there are no triangles in $X$, then if two edges are adjacent and are "in a vertex clique of $v$", the only way for another edge to be adjacent to both of them is to be also connected to $v$. Hence the result. Thanks!